# Pipeline doesn't write to MySQL but also gives no error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, scrapy

I've tried to implement [this pipeline](https://gist.github.com/tzermias/6982723) in my spider.
After installing the necessary dependencies I am able to run the spider without any errors but for some reason it doesn't write to my database.

I'm pretty sure there is something going wrong with connecting to the database. When I give in a wrong password, I still don't get any error.

When the spider scraped all the data, it needs a few minutes before it starts dumping the stats.

```
2017-08-31 13:17:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-08-31 13:17:12 [scrapy] INFO: Stored csv feed (27 items) in: test.csv 
2017-08-31 13:24:46 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Pipeline:

```
import MySQLdb.cursors
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy import log

SETTINGS = {}
SETTINGS['DB_HOST'] = 'mysql.domain.com'
SETTINGS['DB_USER'] = 'username'
SETTINGS['DB_PASSWD'] = 'password'
SETTINGS['DB_PORT'] = 3306
SETTINGS['DB_DB'] = 'database_name'

class MySQLPipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.stats)

    def __init__(self, stats):
        print "init"
        #Instantiate DB
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool ('MySQLdb',
            host=SETTINGS['DB_HOST'],
            user=SETTINGS['DB_USER'],
            passwd=SETTINGS['DB_PASSWD'],
            port=SETTINGS['DB_PORT'],
            db=SETTINGS['DB_DB'],
            charset='utf8',
            use_unicode = True,
            cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        self.stats = stats
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print "close"
        """ Cleanup function, called after crawing has finished to close open
            objects.
            Close ConnectionPool. """
        self.dbpool.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print "process"
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._insert_record, item)
        query.addErrback(self._handle_error)
        return item

    def _insert_record(self, tx, item):
        print "insert"
        result = tx.execute(
        " INSERT INTO matches(type,home,away,home_score,away_score) VALUES (soccer,"+item["home"]+","+item["away"]+","+item["score"].explode("-")[0]+","+item["score"].explode("-")[1]+")" 
        )
        if result > 0:
            self.stats.inc_value('database/items_added')

    def _handle_error(self, e):
        print "error"
        log.err(e)
```

Spider:

```
import scrapy
import dateparser
from crawling.items import KNVBItem

class KNVBspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "knvb"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.knvb.nl/competities/eredivisie/uitslagen',
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'crawling.pipelines.MySQLPipeline': 301,
        }
    }
    def parse(self, response):
        # www.knvb.nl/competities/eredivisie/uitslagen
        for row in response.xpath('//div[@class="table"]'):
            for div in row.xpath('./div[@class="row"]'):
                match = KNVBItem()
                match['home'] = div.xpath('./div[@class="value home"]/div[@class="team"]/text()').extract_first()
                match['away'] = div.xpath('./div[@class="value away"]/div[@class="team"]/text()').extract_first()
                match['score'] = div.xpath('./div[@class="value center"]/text()').extract_first()
                match['date'] = dateparser.parse(div.xpath('./preceding-sibling::div[@class="header"]/span/span/text()').extract_first(), languages=['nl']).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                yield match
```

If there are better pipelines available to do what I'm trying to achieve that'd be welcome as well. Thanks!

Update:
With the link provided in the accepted answer I eventually got to this function that's working (and thus solved my problem):

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print "process"
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._insert_record, item)
    query.addErrback(self._handle_error)
    query.addBoth(lambda _: item)
    return query
```

Comment: Your indentation seems to be wrong. `_insert_error` and `_handle_error` are not part of the Pipeline. Did you check if `process_item` in your pipeline is getting called (printing out something)?

Comment: Updated the code with some prints and fixed indentation. `process_item` is called, as well as all other functions except `_insert_record` and `_handle_error`. I'm actually amazed it gets this far while the connection in the `init` function should fail with a wrong password but for some reason I don't get an error for this.

Comment: @Casper Do you have access to MySQL server logs? If so, try to check it, you might find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [at this](https://github.com/rmax/dirbot-mysql/blob/master/dirbot/pipelines.py) for how to use adbapi with MySQL for saving scraped items. Note the difference in your `process_item` and their `process_item` method implementation. While you return the item immediately, they return `Deferred` object which is the result of `runInteraction` method and which returns the item upon its completion. I think this is the reason your `_insert_record` never gets called.

Comment: I've tested with returning the runInteraction but I get an AttributeError. I've added this to the question.

Comment: I had to add `query.addBoth(lambda _: item)` as it turns out. Now I'm getting a proper error, telling me it can't connect with the server so I'm checking this with my provider. Thanks so far!

Comment: Resolved the last issue with my provider. Thanks for providing this code @Tomáš Linhart

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the insert in your output that's already a good sign.
I'd rewrite the insert function this way:

```
def _insert_record(self, tx, item):
    print "insert"
    raw_sql = "INSERT INTO matches(type,home,away,home_score,away_score) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
    sql = raw_sql % ('soccer', item['home'], item['away'], item['score'].explode('-')[0], item['score'].explode('-')[1])
    print sql
    result = tx.execute(sql)
    if result > 0:
        self.stats.inc_value('database/items_added')
```

It allows you to debug the sql you're using. In you version you're not wrapping the string in `'` which is a syntax error in mysql.
I'm not sure about your last values (score) so I treated them as strings.

Comment: I think he wrote *`process_item` is called, as well as all other functions except `_insert_record`...*

Comment: That's right. It seems as the `_insert_record` is never called. Therefore I don't think a change in this function will make a difference?

Comment: True, I somehow didn't see that.